# Getting this error when using OLS method in jupyter for multiple linear regression -- TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type

Tags: regression

Here is my code:

```
x = sm.add_constant(x1)

results=sm.OLS(y,x).fit()

results.summary()
```

============================================================

TypeError

Traceback (most recent call last)

in

----> 1 x = sm.add_constant(x1)

```
  2 results=sm.OLS(y,x).fit()

  3 results.summary()
```

Comment: removed pandas as it is not related

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.
#[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)